# How do I clear the print spooler on a windows server with a script?

Tags: windows-server-2008, print-spooler

We have many (50+) printers on a Windows 2008 R2 server.  Sometimes a printer (and eventually the spooler...) gets blocked by users accidentally trying to print 100+ page jobs.  And then other users keep trying to print again and again and again, because their jobs are not printing.  They are factory workers and not very computer savvy so they don't know (or care) how to use the printer queue software.

I've seen .BAT scripts to stop the spooler, delete all print jobs, then start the spooler.  But that script requires elevation and the user must run a command prompt as administrator.  I want it so a user with the correct permissions can double-click a script icon to do this task.

Is there a way to run a script (.BAT, .VBS, or .PS) by a non-admin user to clear all jobs from the spooler on Windows 2008?

I would also like to run this script automatically after a reboot, and just delete any print jobs left over in the spooler.

Comment: One option might be to set up a script to do the work that requires elevation and set up a scheduled task to run on a specific event id being created.  Then the non-admin script can create the event log entry to start the task.  This way you can schedule the task to run as whatever user you like, as long as the account can write to the event log then it should work, e.g. EVENTCREATE.exe or PS.  Just ensure that no one can tamper with the elevated task. https://superuser.com/questions/1513335/runas-admin-account-behavior-difficulty#comment2289593_1513335

Comment: Interesting.  I may use that for a different task.  But my task needs to be run by a user on demand, not attached to an event.

Comment: But the task the user runs on demand can create the event.

Comment: I have scripts that (temporarily) elevate the user(using 'runas'), then they could clear the queue. But i think this would only work on the local machine. So they would have to RDP into the print server and run it from there. Just thinking out loud here. But does that sound like it might be do-able?